# How to plot graph in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

how to plot a histogram when turtles leave building after alarm is activated. i do add this code, however seem like not working correctly and the time also not correct. The time on graph suppose same like time in "evacuation time" monitor not display as in tick . can someone advice me on this. thanks in advanced.

```
globals
[
percent-leader
flag-active-alarm
time-to-evacuate
flag-alarm
time-to-exits
]

to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks
set flag-active-alarm false
set time-to-exits [] 
setup-turtles
end

to go
ask turtles [wander fd 0.01]
if (flag-active-alarm )[active-alarm] 
if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simulation
[ stop ] 

if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]
    [ 
     plot-time-to-exits

    ]  
 tick
 end

 to plot-time-to-exits
 set-current-plot "PDF-Escape-Time"
 set-plot-x-range min time-to-exits max time-to-exits
 histogram time-to-exits
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple reasons why it might not be working like you expect (by the way, in general, you should tell us what it is actually currently doing wrong). First off, you have:

```
if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simulation
[ stop ] 

if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]
    [ 
     plot-time-to-exits

    ]
```

The problem here is that, if the turtles are all red at the beginning of this code, than the simulation stop and the second conditional (that calls `plot-time-to-exits` in its body) is never reached. If any turtles are *not* red, then the second conditional is false and its body is never run. Thus, `plot-time-to-exits` is never called.

I think you probably want something more like:

```
if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ] [
  plot-time-to-exits
  stop
]
```

Next, no data is being added to `time-to-exits`. I'm entirely sure what you're trying to plot (nor how 'time in "evacuation time" monitor' is being calculated), but I would expect to see something like `set time-to-exits lput time time-to-exits` somewhere.